# Positioning and spacing of tables

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I'm new to LaTeX and I already know that my question seems too stupid. Actually I'm writing a text as follows:

```
The exact dimensions of the system are listed in Table……\\

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  $Description$ & Value \\ \hline
  Plenum, Cross-sectional area &$192*192 [mm^2] $ \\ \hline
  Plenum Length &$130 [mm]$  \\ \hline
  membrane, Cross-sectional area &$110*110 [mm^2] $ \\ \hline
  Membrane Tickness &$ 5 [mm] $ \\ \hline
  Flame Holder, Cross-sectional area &$4*60 [mm^2] $ \\ \hline
  Flame Holder Height  &$30 [mm] $ \\ \hline 
  Combustion Chamber, Cross-sectional area  &$198*198 [mm^2] $ \\ \hline
Combustion Chamber Height  &$350 [mm] $ \\ \hline  
 Exhaust Port Diameter  &$40 [mm] $ \\ \hline
 Exhaust Port Height  &$5[mm] $ \\ \hline
 Loudspeaker Cutout Diameter  &$186*186 [mm^2] $ \\ \hline 
  \end{tabular}


To model ~\cite{poinsot:hal-00270731} loudspeaker we have to use some electrical and mechanical characteristics of it.~\cite{points} A large part of the required parameters were available in the data sheet provided by producer company and the other features are calculated by formulas.\\
The list of used parameters of loudspeaker are mentioned in Table.\\

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
Description & Value \\ 
\hline 
Voice Coil Resistance  & 3.3 [Ohm] \\ 
\hline 
Suspension compliance & 4.98e-4 [m/N] \\ 
\hline 
Suspension mechanical losses & 1.22 [N*s/m] \\ 
\hline 
Force factor & 4.5 [T*m] \\ 
\hline 
Voice coil inductance & 0.7 [mH] \\ 
\hline 
Voice coil loss factor & 0.2 \\ 
\hline 
Driving voltage (Peak) & 0.05 [V] \\ 
\hline 
Moving mass (Including Acoustic Load) & 23 [gr] \\ 
\hline 
Fundamental resonant frequency & 47 [Hz] \\ 
\hline 
Electrical Q factor & 1.44 \\ 
\hline 
Mechanical Q factor & 5.56 \\ 
\hline 
Total Q factor of driver & 1.14 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

The problem is that the tables are on the left side of the page and there is no space between the first table and the text below it. I would be really thankful if you helped me.

Comment: Can you please complete your code snippet to an compilable minimal working example so that we can copy and play with it to help you?

Comment: Welcome to `TeX.SX`. Firstly, I advise against the usage of  the double slash, \\, to force a linebreak. Secondly, `\vspace{<dimension>}` or `\vskip<dimension>` with `<dimension>` some unit of space, e.g. `10pt` may or may not be what you're looking for to create vertical space.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to wanting to center each table horizontally and to leave some vertical white space above and below the tables, you also appear to need to be able to cross-reference the tabular material. I therefore suggest you encase each `tabular` environment in a `table` environment, insert the instruction `\centering` immediately after the `\begin{table}` statement, use `\caption{...}` to assign aa numbered caption, and `\label{...}` to create a "label" that can be used as the argument of `\ref{...}` elsewhere in the document.

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{System dimensions} \label{tab:sys_dimen}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  Description & Value \\ \hline
  ...
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: thank you about your comments. I added \begin{table} and \centering to the beginning of my table and add \end{table} to the end of it. but when I run it the position of the table moves to other part of the text!! I mean, It will go to up among some others sentences of the text!!!

Comment: @ShahinMohamadnejad - please read the posting [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001). If you absolutely don't want a `table` environment to float, please search this site and you'll find lots of possible solutions. I would like to suggest, though, that you learn to trust LaTeX to handle (most of) the chores of placing floats and concentrate on perfecting the *contents* of the floats. By the way, typographically speaking, always placing a float smack between two paragraphs is rarely satisfactory.